# sending many commands to cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, runtime-error

I'm trying to send the `cmd` many commands according to the answers he sends me.

I'm getting a run time error message:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

When I'm running something like this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
answer = process.communicate(input="some command\n" + '\n')[0]

"""
choosing another command according to answer
"""

print process.communicate(input=another_command + '\n')[0]
process.kill()
```

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: could you provide a bigger picture? Are you sending your commands after `process.kill()`? If not, can you provide some example of code (with a real commands instead of `"some command"`)?
There's  a chance that a command you try to run in cmd terminates your shell.

Comment: Even without the `process.kill()`  and both commands as `"ipconfig\n"`. The first command is working and the second one gives me the Runtime Error

Comment: Executing a command probably sends a returncode back, closing the Popen object. For example, if you execute the ipconfig then do `process.poll()` you will probably see the `0` return code.

Comment: Yes it doe's show `0`, is there any way to avoid the closing of the `Popen object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not send your commands to cmd.exe. Call your commands directly like:

```
subprocess.Popen("dir", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Perhaps you will not need the pipe for stdin if you use it this way.

Comment: And if i want to do it using `sub-processing` and `communicate()`, is that possible or not? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @EyalS Is your task to use subprocessing and communicate() or to solve a special problem? 
You can use communicate to pipe input into an interactive comand. But I don't think you can use it to pipe commands to cmd.

Comment: from some reason my computer doesn't recognize cmd.exe as a system program even tho all my paths are perfectly right, that caused me to try and bypass the problem using subprocessing,

Comment: Nope, when i try I get an error like this `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think i understood you

Comment: @EyalS, the `dir` command is built into cmd.exe.  There is no `dir.exe`. With `shell=True` the  actual command line that `Popen` executes is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "dir"`. I assume by "custom command" that jhinghaus meant an external command such as `ipconfig.exe` or `python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is normal. `communicate` closes the standard input of the subprocess to indicate that no more input is pending so that the subprocess can flush its output. So you cannot chain multiple `communicate` calls on one single subprocess.

But if you commands are simple enough (not many kbytes of input data), and if you do not need to collect and process the output of one command before sending the next one, you should be able to write all the commands in sequence, reading as much output as possible between two of them. After last command, you could then close the subprocess standard input and wait for it to terminate, still collating the output:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("some command\n\n")
partial_answer = process.stdout.read()  # all or part of the answer can still be buffered subprocess side
...
process.stdin.write("some other command\n\n")
...
# after last command, time to close subprocess
process.stdin.close()
retcode = None
while True:
    end_of_answer += process.stdout.read()
    if retcode is not None: break
```

Comment: Watch out for a deadlock if you're not using a dedicated reader thread. In Windows you can call [`PeekNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365779) to get the number of bytes available, using the handle from `msvcrt.get_osfhandle(process.stdout.fileno())`. That way you won't deadlock trying to read more data that what's available, while cmd.exe is blocked waiting for a command on stdin. For working with a shell you can also set a custom prompt and read a byte at a time until the prompt is read.

Comment: Also, pass `bufsize=0` to prevent buffering `process.stdin` if you don't want to have to call `flush` repeatedly, and cmd.exe needs the line ending to be `"\r\n"` , not `"\n\n"`.